# delete from Table where it reference column in same table

Tags: mysql

i have to delete from 2 tables using the reference from the the first table.

the structure is as follows:

```
t1.id = t1.parent
t2.division = t1.id
```

i need to delete the parent and all its children cause the parent column may have children and those children may be parent to another

any advice  would be appreciated

```
DELETE division, job_definition  FROM division
INNER JOIN job_definition 
ON division.`id` = job_definition.`division` 
WHERE parent = 10
```

the query below does delete all the children as i would like it to do

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: it only deletes the first parent  but not the children of the parents i've deleted

Comment: Can you show the table structure of both the tables?

Comment: Why don't you use a foreign key with DELETE CASCADE? By this way you just delete the parent table and all children will be deleted automatically.